# oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment (execution halted)

Tags: r, google-analytics-api, httr

Trying to run an R script (seen below) in batch and I am getting the error oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment and then it halts execution.  I found the oath_listener() is a part of the httr package.  The code runs fine from R Studio, just won't run as Rscript.exe?

```
require(RODBC)
require(RSQLite)
require(RGoogleAnalytics)
require(httpuv)
require(httr)

client.secret <- "xxx"
client.id <- "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"

token <- Auth(client.id,client.secret)
save(token,file="./token_file")
ValidateToken(token)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe run it once interactively to save the token file, then load the token file when you want to run it in batch  mode. You can test for it's existence using...

```
if(file.exists("./token_file")){
  load("./token_file")
}else{
  token <- Auth(client.id,client.secret)
}
```

Comment: This was a great idea, however - still getting the same error :/

Comment: Also httr does that for you automatically

Comment: @AustinTrombley were you able to fix the problem ?

Comment: Yes, I had to save the token file to a static place / not a temp folder

Answer (score 0):

When you run your R Script inside R Studio or R it has a defined working directory that you can check by the following command: `getwd()`.
When you run you script inside a batch file it can have a different working directory, therefore not finding the token file you need.
So, you can first check the directory running the command `getwd()` inside R Studio and then insert the command `setwd("same working directory from R Studio")` in your script to set the directory to the same you use inside RStudio.